# How to detect USRP usb type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, usrp

When i include [uhd/usb_control.hpp](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/765f6735e661fb5a986451ded984d85675832294/host/include/uhd/transport/usb_control.hpp) in my main.cpp :

```cpp
#include <uhd/transport/usb_control.hpp>

/* Some other includes */

int main (void)
{
    uhd::transport::usb_control::sptr usbSpeed;

    usbSpeed = uhd::transport::usb_control::make(handle, 0);
    /* `handle` is a `usb_device_handle::vid_pid_pair_t` */
}
```

I got error from [here](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/765f6735e661fb5a986451ded984d85675832294/host/include/uhd/transport/usb_control.hpp#L32):

```cpp
static sptr make(usb_device_handle::sptr handle, const int interface);
```

**Error:**
*unexpected token struct. Did you forget a ';'*
*struct: missing tag name*

And another strange error in:

```cpp
usbSpeed = uhd::transport::usb_control::make(handle, 0);
```

**Error:**
  *Cannot convert argument 2 from `int` to `const int`*

The only implementation that i find for `uhd::transport::usb_control::make` is [uhd/transport/usb_dummy_impl.cpp](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/master/host/lib/transport/usb_dummy_impl.cpp#L37) which only throw an exception.

> **Environment information:**
>   *Compiler*: MS Visual Studio 2017
>   *OS*: MS Windows 10
>   *C++ Standard*: 17

How to fix those errors ? I only what to detect the USRP usb type. For this i read the uhd source code and i find the uhd/transport/usb_control.hpp, But I have encountered those errors.

Comment: Your return type is wrong, it should be of type `sptr` which is `typedef std::shared_ptr<usb_control> sptr;`. See `static sptr make(usb_device_handle::sptr handle, const int interface);`.

Comment: @AndreKampling, Sorry it was a typing error now is correct.

Comment: @is your file saved as '.C' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the cause of this unexpected behavior is related to your included files and a conflict between some of them, as you mentioned in addition of `#include <uhd/transport/usb_control.hpp>` you have some other includes. i suggest move this include line upper and lower of other includes and test your code again.

wish my suggest be useful.